# "Tiempo" vs "clima"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, significado, colombia

Cuando estuve en Colombia, escuchaba mucho las frases como:

> Hoy hace buen clima en Bogotá.
>
> Hace buen clima para Caracas este viernes.

¿Es correcto usar la palabra clima para hablar acerca del estado atmosférico?

Comment: En España, no se utiliza la palabra clima para referirse al estado del tiempo puntualmente, sino, a lo largo del tiempo. Por ejemplo: en las noticias, cuando quieren hablar de la predicción meteorológica (weather forecast) se utiliza el término "el tiempo". Ya que se refiere al estado puntual de la meteorología. Es posible, que en otros lugares de habla hispana, se utilicen ambos términos indistintamente, pero a mi entender hay un matiz de diferencia, y no sería del todo correcto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El tiempo se refiere al estado puntual de la atmósfera, en un momento y lugar determinados.
El clima se refiere a la sucesión periódica de tipos de estado atmosférico, para un lugar determinado y a lo largo del tiempo (sucesivos momentos).

Dos lugares geográficos con climas diferentes pueden tener en un momento dado iguales estados atmosféricos. Por ejemplo:
Hoy hace un día lluvioso tanto en Caracas como en Mérida.

No obstante, las expresiones populares que conforman las particularidades del idioma evolucionan a lo largo del tiempo de forma distinta en diferentes lugares.

No puedo afirmar rotundamente que sea así, pero encuentro muchos sitios web colombianos que utilizan indistintamente ambos términos para referirse a una predicción meteorológica.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con Blas Soriano. Clima es un término relativamente atemporal. En España, por ejemplo, tenemos clima continental en la mayor parte del pais y clima mediterráneo en el este. Y el tiempo de España a veces es bueno y a veces malo. Aunque no es del todo correcto, aquí tienes una imagen con los climas del mundo: http://wctawildanimalparkp8.weebly.com/uploads/1/4/3/7/14374388/3861164.gif?423